# Filtered statistics created on one table used for cardinality estimation of another table in a TSQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can filtered statistics created on one table be used for cardinality estimation of another table in a TSQL query?

The code sample that i pasted below has comes from http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2013/10/29/fixing-cardinality-estimation-errors-with-filtered-statistics/?awt_l=OGZ5i&awt_m=3sMpQpfwa9YUUTS

```
-- Create a new database
CREATE DATABASE FilteredStatistics
GO

-- Use it
USE FilteredStatistics
GO

-- Create a new table
CREATE TABLE Country
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
Name VARCHAR(100)
) 
GO

-- Create a new table
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
ID INT, 
SalesAmount DECIMAL(18, 2)
) 
GO

-- Create a Non-Clustered Index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_Name ON Country(Name) 
GO

-- Create a Clustered Index
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_ID_SalesAmount ON Orders(ID, SalesAmount) 
GO

-- Insert a few records into the Lookup Table
INSERT INTO Country VALUES(0, 'Austria') 
INSERT INTO Country VALUES(1, 'UK')
INSERT INTO Country VALUES(2, 'France') 
GO

-- Insert uneven distributed order data
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(0, 0)

DECLARE @i INT = 1 

WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1, @i) 
SET @i += 1
END
GO

-- Update the Statistics on both tables
UPDATE STATISTICS Country WITH FULLSCAN 
UPDATE STATISTICS Orders WITH FULLSCAN 
GO

--incorrect row estimate for Orders table
SELECT SalesAmount FROM Country
INNER JOIN Orders ON Country.ID = Orders.ID
WHERE Name = 'UK'

--create filtered statistics on table country
CREATE STATISTICS Country_UK ON Country(ID) 
WHERE Name = 'UK'

--correct row estimate for Orders table
SELECT SalesAmount FROM Country
INNER JOIN Orders ON Country.ID = Orders.ID
WHERE Name = 'UK'
```

Before filtered statistics were created, you note that the estimated number of rows returned from Orders table is 500.5 which is an estimate derived from the density vector(1001 * .5) on the orders table.

[image: Execution plan info]

Here is the density vector and histogram for Orders table
[image: Statistics object]

After filtered stats were created on table Country, the estimate of rows returned from Order table is correct. How are filtered stats on table Country helping with cardinality estimation in table Orders?
[image: Correct cardinality estimation]

Comment: Why do you think the histogram is available for the `Name` column in the `idx_ID_SalesAmount` index? The histogram in that case is available for the `ID` column (**key of the index that is being used**) and if your search would be `where Orders.ID = 1` you would get the estimated number of rows = 1000.

Comment: You are absolutely correct on that point. I had a brain fade i reckon when i had asked this question. Let me rephrase the question as I still do not understand as to why creating filtered statistics on Country table get us a correct estimate for Orders table. I will edit the question to reflect that.